How many tangents to a curve are there that are parallel to a secant line that passes through two, infinitely close, points on the curve?
In order to find the slope of the tangent to, for example, $f(x) = x^2$ at the point $x = a$, I first look for the slope of the secant line that passes through two infinitely close points $Po(a, f(a))$ and $P(a+dx, f(a+dx))$. The slope of the secant line and the slope of the tangent line must be the same at least once on the interval $[a, a+dx]$.
Is there only one tangent line through $Po$ that is parallel to the secant line through $Po$ and $P$?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Two points cannot be infinite close.
